# How to read 'H3' as 3 H values?

Tags: python

For example, if I enter CH3CH3 currently using counter, my program will read it as just 2 'H' in total, unlike the 6 that I want. How do I work around this? Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it using `regex` :

```
import re
line  =  "CH3CH3"
match = re.findall('H(\d+)', line)
print(sum(map(int, match)),"H")
```

It gives o/p like :

```
6 H
```

Comment: Thanks. I have not heard of regex before so I will take a look at it. Looks like it could be quite useful for what I want.